# I'm trying to grab a card token through Stripe.js library but get Uncaught IntegrationError

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

Below is the calling function

```
        function getToken(data, TokenData) {
        var stripe = Stripe(data.StripeID), // Check
            c = {
                "number": data.Cardnum,
                "cvc": data.Cvv,
                "exp_month": data.Expiry.getMonth() + 1,
                "exp_year": data.Expiry.getFullYear(),
                "name": data.NameOnCard,
                "currency": data.CurrencyCulture
            };
        stripe.createToken(c, (status, result)=>{
            if (result.error) {
                alert(result.error.message);
            }
            else {
                data.stripToken = result.token;
                return TokenData(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

The error I get in the console:
Uncaught IntegrationError: You must provide a Stripe Element or a valid token type to create a Token.

I'm not sure about the card object.  I'm using stripe.js v3.

Answer (score 1):

When using Stripe.js v3, you do not pass card details directly to the `createToken` function.

Instead, you need to pass in the instance to your "card" element (created from Stripe Elements): https://stripe.com/docs/js/tokens_sources/create_token?type=cardElement

More here on how to set up Stripe Elements: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#set-up-stripe-elements

Comment: Yeah.  I've created stripe elements.  The card does not mount because the form is created in a different iframe.  So I'm stuck.